# How to change the width of tinymce preview window?

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

i have tried with the following scenario

```
.mce-window-head .mce-container-body .mce-abs-layout .mce-panel .mce-foot{
        width: 900px !important;
        left: 215px !important;
    }
```

I want to change the width of the preview window. Can you help me how to change it? i have tried with the above option but i cant able to fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the with and height of the preview-plugin with the options `plugin_preview_width` and `plugin_preview_height`

```
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas",
        plugins : "preview",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "preview",
        plugin_preview_width : "500", //This do the trick
        plugin_preview_height : "600"
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Adding some context to your answer makes for a higher-quality answer. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `editor_plugin.js` file under   `tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/preview`.

Find this bit:

```
_preview: function () {
            var ed = this.editor, win, html, c, pos, pos2, css, i, 
 page = ed.getParam("plugin_preview_pageurl", null), 
 w = ed.getParam("plugin_preview_width", "600"), 
 h = ed.getParam("plugin_preview_height", "800");
```

Mine is set to 600*800.